# Pytest PropertyMock as return_value for MagicMock does not get invoked

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I am trying to mock the `return_value` for a `MagicMock` instance as a `PropertyMock` but it appears to be returning the `PropertyMock` object without invoking it i.e. does not return the actual value.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        # ...
        fields = (
            "my_field"
        )

    my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_my_field(self, instance):
        other_models = instance.other_models.filter(stuff="stuff")
        if other_models:
            # returns <class 'unittest.mock.PropertyMock'> instead of an actual value
            print(type(other_models.get().my_property))
            # throws error since it isn't receiving a string
            return ujson.loads(other_models.get().my_property)
        return {}


# test case
def test_hello(mocker):
    expected_value = ujson.dumps({'hello': 2})
    instance_mock = mocker.MagicMock()
    other_model_mock = mocker.MagicMock()
    other_model_mock.get().my_property = mocker.PropertyMock(return_value=expected_value)
    instance_mock.other_models.filter.return_value = other_model_mock

    serializer = MySerializer()
    observed_value = serializer.get_my_field(instance_mock)
    assert expected_value == observed_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not need to set `other_model_mock` to be a `MagicMock` simply setting it to be a `PropertyMock` worked

```
expected_value = {'hello', 2}
instance_mock = mocker.MagicMock()
other_model_mock = mocker.PropertyMock()
other_model_mock.get().my_property.return_value = ujson.dumps(expected_value)
instance_mock.other_models.filter.return_value = other_model_mock
# ...
```